# PHP curl_errno returns 7 even when request is successful

Tags: php, curl, authorize.net, php-curl

I'm trying to integrate authorize.net (AIM) using the official PHP SDK v2.0.0 and I'm seeing some strange behaviors:

1. `curl_exec()` returns `false` even when the request is successful and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set to `true`.
2. `curl_errno` is returns 7 (Failed to connect() to host or proxy) for the same request.

I know request is successful since:

1. I can see the transaction is successfully recorded at authorize.net
2. Setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `false` causes the JSON response from authorize.net to be printed
3. `curl_getinfo()` shows HTTP status code = 200

Anyone experience this type of behavior with cURL? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**EDIT**: Added output with `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` set

```
*   Trying 198.241.206.22:443...
* Connected to apitest.authorize.net (198.241.206.22) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/app/demo/assets/lib/anet_sdk_2.0.0/lib/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Foster City; O=Authorize.Net; CN=*.authorize.net
*  start date: Feb  5 20:44:08 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 15 21:14:08 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "apitest.authorize.net" matched cert's "*.authorize.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /xml/v1/request.api HTTP/1.1
Host: apitest.authorize.net
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/json
Content-Length: 1458

* upload completely sent off: 1458 out of 1458 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace: a2_fe4a070f-cf07-47d7-8e9e-c8a703920de5-5628-7089051
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,cache-control,content-type,origin,method,SOAPAction
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,OPTIONS,POST,GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-Cnection: close
< Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 10:40:48 GMT
< Content-Length: 512
<
* Connection #0 to host apitest.authorize.net left intact
```

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log

Comment: Edited post to include the output using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`.

Comment: weird, i don't have any idea why it would return 7 either... can you post a minimal-ish code to reproduce it?